# restoring mysqldump over internet connection issues?

Tags: mysql

I am moving servers between providers and I am going to do a mysqldump inside their network and then load the file to the remote database over the Internet using `mysql --host .. < dump.sql`.

As long as I can connect to the remote mysql server are their any restrictions/problems? I would guess it would take longer but I am more concerned if there is reliability issues. I am moving between 2 well known cloud providers.

Comment: Personally, my approach would be to transfer the `dump.sql` file from one host to the other. I'd verify the integrity of the file e.g. getting a checksum on each copy of the file, and then compare the checksum.

Answer (score 1):

If your connection is good there should be no problems. Normally writing the data out takes way longer than transmitting the statements so bandwidth, so long as adequate, is rarely an issue.

For long restores you want to ensure your connection stays alive, so you'll need one that's reliable, and that you don't interrupt the process. Being on wireless on a laptop might be a bad idea, it could cut, you might close it, etc.

What I find works best is doing a `mysqldump`, checking it, copying it over with `rsync` and then doing a restore remotely.

Answer (score 0):

you can always SCP of FTP file to remote machine and do it locally. This way chances of data corruption due to network hiccups are far less.

Otherwise it's the same, i would say.